# Return value from one stored procedure to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to use the return value from one stored procedure to another stored procedure. I was searching on the internet and try several solutions, but all of them are not working, I don't know what the mistake I make.

The stored procedure that I want to use its return value is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pro_ForeignKeyCheck
     (@tableName VARCHAR(100),
      @columnName VARCHAR(100),
      @idValue INT) 
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE fksCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
        SELECT 
            tc.table_name, ccu.column_name
        FROM
            information_schema.table_constraints tc 
        JOIN
            information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu ON tc.constraint_name = ccu.constraint_name 
        JOIN
            information_schema.referential_constraints rc ON tc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name 
        JOIN
            information_schema.table_constraints tc2 ON rc.unique_constraint_name = tc2.constraint_name 
        JOIN
            information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu2 ON tc2.constraint_name = ccu2.constraint_name 
        WHERE
            tc.constraint_type = 'Foreign Key' 
            AND tc2.table_name = @tableName 
            AND ccu2.column_name = @columnName
        ORDER BY
            tc.table_name

    DECLARE @fkTableName VARCHAR(100),
            @fkColumnName VARCHAR(100),
            @fkFound BIT,
            @params NVARCHAR(100),
            @sql NVARCHAR(500)

    OPEN fksCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM fksCursor INTO @fkTableName, @fkColumnName

    SET @fkFound = 0
    SET @params = N'@fkFound BIT OUTPUT'

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 AND COALESCE(@fkFound, 0) <> 1 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'set @fkFound = (select top 1 1 from [' + @fkTableName + '] where [' + @fkColumnName + '] = ' + cast(@idValue as varchar(10)) + ')'
        PRINT @sql

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @fkFound OUTPUT

        FETCH NEXT FROM fksCursor INTO @fkTableName, @fkColumnName
    END

    CLOSE fksCursor
    DEALLOCATE fksCursor

    SELECT COALESCE(@fkFound, 0)
    RETURN 0
END
```

and this use to check if the primary key value used in all child tables, we call it like this

```
EXECUTE  pro_ForeignKeyCheck 'tablename','columnName', 1
```

or

```
EXECUTE  pro_ForeignKeyCheck @tablename = 'tablename', @columnName = 'columnName', @idValue = 1
```

and it will work, but I cannot use the return value in other stored procedure

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[pro_Delete_acount]
    @UserID int,
    @Action NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE  @count int , @ErrNo int , @ErrMsg varchar(2000), @exit int



    set @exit=0
    if @Action ='ADMIN'
    begin
    /*---------Call Store Procedure pro_ForeignKeyCheck to check if there is value are exit in child table*/
    --EXEC  @exit = pro_ForeignKeyCheck1 @tablename='tb_M_admin',@columnName='admin_id',@idValue= @UserID 
    --select @exit

    --EXEC   @exit = pro_ForeignKeyCheck  @tablename='tb_M_admin',@columnName='admin_id',@idValue= 1

    EXEC @exit = pro_ForeignKeyCheck 'tb_M_admin','admin_id', 0 
    --select @exit

    select -2[Ret_Status],@exit[ErrNo],0[ErrMsg] -- test 

    end
end
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks all

Comment: possibly you need to use `output` keyword somewhere in your SPs

Comment: Dear @AlexKudryashev, i try but it's not work

Comment: You need to create stored procedure with out parameter.
you can refer below article for reference
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/794765/sql-server-how-to-write-stored-procedures-with-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
@Status int OUTPUT
```

in the `pro_ForeignKeyCheck` so it starts with

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pro_ForeignKeyCheck1
@tableName VARCHAR(100),
@columnName VARCHAR(100),
@idValue int,
@Status int OUTPUT
```

and at the end of it did as follow

```
--select coalesce(@fkFound,0)
select @Status = coalesce(@fkFound,0)
--return 0
```

stop the last to line and add new one

In the other stored procedure,  call it as follows

```
EXEC  pro_ForeignKeyCheck1 'tb_M_admin','admin_id', 0 ,@exit output 
select @exit
```

and now the return value will be used.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC @exit = pro_ForeignKeyCheck 'tb_M_admin','admin_id', 0 

---
select coalesce(@fkFound,0)
return 0 --< this will be assigned to @exit
```

replace this code with

```
return IsNull(@fkFound, 0)
```

You may leave `select` for other purposes but it cannot affect `RETURN` value. So you may remove it either.

Comment: Test your `cursor` code - does it return anything at all?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tb_M_admin WHERE admin_id = 0 ` - does this return anything?

Comment: dear in my example I try right and wrong admin_id and all return same thing, but now I try as @alex-Kudryashev said and o get it. thanks a lot to all

Answer (score 0):

This is oversimplified example of call of one SP from another. I hope it will give you some ideas.

```
create procedure dbo.first_proc
@bd datetime,
@d int output
as
select @d= DATEDIFF(day,@bd,getdate()) 
go

create procedure dbo.sec_proc
@birthday datetime
as
declare @days int
exec dbo.first_proc @birthday, @days output

select 'you live '+cast(@days as varchar) + ' days' result
go

exec dbo.sec_proc '1959-09-17'
```

Comment: Thanks dear @alex-Kudryashev i get the idea